# Nullable reference types on object array

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

I've a .NET 6 project with non-nullable reference types.

I want to constrain the objects parameter to a non-nullable array of nullable objects.

I've 4 possible methods and assume one of these should work.

```
public void Method1(object[] objects)

public void Method2(object[]? objects)

public void Method3(object?[] objects)

public void Method4(object?[]? objects)
```

Method2 and 4 both accept a null. So I'm left with 1 and 3 but I get a warning on both:

*CS8625 Cannot convert null literal to non-nullable reference type*

I would expect method3 to work without warning:

```
Method3(new object[] { null });
```

Is there any way to get this done?

My question is answered in one of the comments. I should of course have used:

```
 Method3(new object?[] { null });
```

Comment: The error is from your declaration of the parameter, not from the definition of the method.

Comment: `new object?[] { null }`

Comment: Looks like typo - `new object[] { null }` *is not* `object?[] objects`... Unless it is the exact question - but than why you expect `null` to satisfy non-nullable `object`?

Comment: Am I missing something? `public void Method3(object?[] objects)` should do? (My IDE isn't giving the "CS8625 Cannot convert null literal to non-nullable reference type" warning)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This answer is just for completeness, so that the answer is not only in the comments*

The problem is not with the declaration of your method and it's parameters, but instead with the call. You are creating an array of non-nullable objects and initializing it with one `null`. You should instead create an array of nullable objects like this: `new object?[] { null }`

To answer your confusion with the method declarations:

The nullability operator always referes to the previous type.

So in `object[]?` the nullability operator applies only to the array. This means that `null` and an array of non-nullable objects would fit this type.

When you write `object?[]`, the nullability operator applies only to `object`. This means that a non-nullable array of nullable objects matches this type.